# PHP Insert with foreign key relation

Tags: php, mysqli

first at all thank you very mucho for read it.

I have a problem making insert sentences.

I have the connection making right and all those things cause i can insert that in other table

BUUUUUT in this table i have a foreign key relation with another table called langs

so the language_id is a foreign key from langs table and i have data in langs tabla and the information match...

but i dont know if i'm making right the query, the only int is the language_id, others are varchar

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_password,name,lastname,mail,language_id) VALUES ('test','test','test','test','test',1)";
```

I have made this query to test if any data is inserted :( but doesnt work

Maybe someone have an ideA?

Regards

Comment: What happens when you execute this query? any error message?

Comment: google.com: `sql insert foreign key` ...

Comment: is there an entry in the langs table with an id of 1?

Comment: If it seems hard, you can use GUI tool to establish foreign relationships and maintain referential integrity.